# users can visit pages with an unwanted URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I use this structure for my post URL in my Wordpress website.

> Domain.com/%post_id%/%postname%

if you delete the /%postname% part you will go to the same page? 
i mean

> Domain.com/post_id/postname  =  domain.com/post_id

Is there any way that when a user visit domain.com/post_id gets redirect to Domain.com/post_id/postname ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.
I suggest adding an [action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to an early event, maybe `wp`?

```
add_action("wp", function() {
    if((is_single() || is_page()) && preg_match("!^/\d+/?$!", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
        http_response_code(301);
        header("Location: " . get_permalink());
        exit;
    }
});
```

This will run on every request and check whether that request is a) a page or post AND b) the REQUEST_URI (=local part of the URL) starts with a slash, followed by numbers, followed by an optional final slash, and nothing else. If these two conditions are met, it will return a HTTP 301 response code ("Redirect Permanent") with a Location header indicating the correct URL.

Put it into your functions.php.

It's interesting that WordPress will automatically redirect /123/postti to /123/posttitle, but it won't to the same for /123. /123/ will be redirected to /123. The code snippet I posted will take care of /123 and /123/, while wordpress takes care of those with a partial title.